# Issuing a single command with multiple lines

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to execute the following line in Windows batch file:

```
CALL createdoc.bat --create=yes --summary="my summary goes here" --publisher="my publisher name goes here" --website="my website address" --details="details.doc" --license="license.doc" --tocfile="../../../toc.doc"
```

When the number of arguments is more than 3, the line is very long. I have tried the following thing to make the batch file look clean and easy to read.

```
CALL createdoc.bat --create=yes \
                   --summary="my summary goes here" \
                   --publisher="my publisher name goes here" \
                   --website="my website address" \
                   --details="details.doc" --license="license.doc" \
                   --tocfile="../../../toc.doc"
```

However it does not work. The cmd does not understand they are separate commands. My question is: How do make my batch file look clean but still get the "cmd" understand the CALL lines making up a single command.

Comment: Try instead of '\'. a caret '^'

Answer (score 1):

The "\" is not supported, you need to put a "^" before the back slash, (^).

I'm not saying that it's going to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
CALL createdoc.bat --create=yes ^
  --summary="my summary goes here" ^
  --publisher="my publisher name goes here" ^
  --website="my website address" ^
  --details="details.doc" --license="license.doc" ^
  --tocfile="../../../toc.doc"
```

Answer (score 0):

The (^) it was an error, you have to put `(^\)`, be cause the `\` is used to specify path in a disk, but i'm not sure.

Here's all the exceptions: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

Answer (score 0):

\ character is usually used for MAC OS X to separate lines. On Windows OS, you can use ^ instead of \ character